# Paginate not working with thumbs up gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, this is a project I'm working on. I've finally got the [thumbs up](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) gem to rank correctly.

However, now paginate no longer is showing.

**The code**

**song_controller.rb snippit**

```
 # GET /Songs.json
  def index
    if params[:genre]
      @songs = Song.tagged_with(params[:genre]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
      get_last_song
    else      
      @songs = Song.order('plusminus').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15) 
      @songs = Song.plusminus_tally.order('plusminus_tally DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
      get_last_song
    end
  end

 def vote_for
      @song = Song.find(params[:id])
      current_user.vote_for(@song)
      @song.plusminus = @song.votes_for
      @song.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render 'update_votes' }
      end
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="song_list">
      <%= render @songs %>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="pagination-centered">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <div class="prev">
      <% if @songs.previous_page %>
        <%= link_to "Back", params.merge(page: @songs.previous_page) %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="next">
      <% if @songs.next_page %>
        <%= link_to "More", params.merge(page: @songs.next_page) %>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34819/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-18052184-paginate-not-working-with-thumbs-up-g

Comment: You haven't told us what the error is. Can you please give us an example?

Comment: I am un-able to respond on chat I don't know why it says "Only users nominated by the room owner may talk here. See the faq for more information. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

order desc in postrgres doesn't work as in mysql: [Postgres sorting problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199706/postgres-sorting-problem)

```
  def index
    if params[:genre]
      @songs = Song.tagged_with(params[:genre]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
      get_last_song
    else      
      @songs = Song.order('plusminus desc nulls last').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
      get_last_song
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this github thread: https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up/issues/64

Also you can remove this line from your code:

```
@songs = Song.order('plusminus').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
```